# How can I accept pastes from the clipboard in my UserControl?

Tags: wpf, clipboard, copy-paste

I've got a UserControl that, oddly enough, bundles a bunch of other controls and logic into a tidy little package.  It has a Text property that accepts a `string` and does magic, displaying the results for the user.  Awesome.

I get that text from a TextBox.  The user pastes text from the clipboard in the textbox, which is bound to a DP on my UserControl.

What I'd like to do is cut out the middle man and accept pastes within my UserControl.

I've already tried using the [DataObject.Pasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.pasting.aspx) attached event, but that appears not to work.

How do you do it?

---

Answered my own question with my current solution, but honestly it "smells".  If anybody has a better answer, please add it and if it works and is better I'll select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My brain fired.  [Command Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx).  Now I know when someone tries to paste and can take it from there.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
        Command="Paste"
        Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

(excuse the bad code; trying to get this working for now) And the event handler:

```
try
{
    var text = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text) as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        return;
    Lines = new Lines(text);
    e.Handled = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Paste failed", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
```

This smells, IMHO.  But I'm not sure how else to handle this.

Comment: Could not managed to make it work. Please refer to an an article that deals with this problem and its solution: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421862/Copy-and-Paste-in-WPF-User-Control